# Finding right bug tracker web application

Tags: web-applications, bug, applications, system

I'm looking for a bug tracking system (similiar as http://www.mantisbt.org) with these following requirements:

---

Requirement specifications are:

1. Upload picture and different files without any limitaton of the file's space.
2. If user belong to a specific group or businesss group, the GUI:s logotype should be changed into group's logotype after the user has entered user name and password. All user use the same database with different GUI.
3. Right information of unassigned, modified and resolved bug case will be displayed based on what group or business group that the user is assigned to.
4. All information will display after the user has logged in.
5. Enable to create 1 or more super user (administrator) and regular user.
6. Right user with right group or business group will retrieve right information.

Non functional requirement:

1. The bugging tracker take place in a webbapplication.
2. All information must use web browser to view all information.

---

Comment: Can you mention what applications you have dismissed until now and for what reasons.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/ might do the trick.
Not sure about the GUI logo though, but it has a lot of features.

Comment: Also, do you want it to integrate with a source control system?

Comment: Also what is your budget?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention your infrastructure but where I work we use [BugNET](http://www.bugnetproject.com/) for one of our projects. If you're running on IIS then it's worth a look. From your list of requirements it'll satisfy most of them. Each defined project within BugNET can have its own logo, I don't think it's possible to alter the logo on a per-user or per-user group basis. It is open-source however so you could, in theory, add that feature yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention whether you are looking for an open source or proprietary solution. Check out [Issue Tracking Anywhere](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/bug-tracking-issue-tracking-anywhere.aspx) if you like. All features are supported except the changing logo on a per-user group basis one. It's free for the first 15 users.

Disclaimer: I am with the company which produces the product.

Comment: In my case, it doesn't matter if it open source or proprietary solution